# How to enable batching in angular-apolo-client

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I want to enable batching in angular apolo client.Somehow I am not able to pass the shouldbatch=true param to the Angular Client constructor

Comment: You should give us an example with your code and some more info about your setup so we can help you.

Comment: Sure thanks for the prompt  reply.

Comment: Sure thanks for the prompt  reply.  Our code looks something like this 
     import {Apollo} from "angular-apollo";
public class QueryService()
{
constructor(private apollo:Apollo)
{
}
// Sorry could not write the specific query down sue to company policies
private getQuery<Tresult>(query)
{
return this.apololo.query<TResult>(query).map(result=>result.data);
}
}

Comment: Also this paste contains the code http://paste.openstack.org/show/718729/

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure your server supports batched queries. You can use the BatchHttpLink class and learn more about it on the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http.html) and [Angular-Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/network-layer.html#query-batching).

Comment: Thanks. What should be done to enable batch loading at the server. We are currently using FBs dataloader for batching and caching.The Dataloader bypasses each resolver call to the model.